# Lost admin access after disk clone although can still log in but just cannot access anything that needs admin rights

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator, clone

I have a very strange and annoying problem.  My 128GB SSD drive which was the boot drive with Windows 7 pro installed was full so I got a 1TB SSD and cloned the old drive to the new one using minitool partition wizard free.  I then booted from the new drive but didn't disconnect the old one.  I logged in as normal but then couldn't access anything that requires Admin rights although my account still shows it's an Administrator account.  I then disconnected the new drive and booted from the old one but had exactly the same problem!  It seems I've been demoted to a standard user on both drives even though they both say I'm an admin.  I've tried many things to try and fix this but as I can't access regedit, user account settings, Adminstrator cmd, services etc I'm basically like a standard user so don't have access to anything that's useful to fix the problem.

Whenever I try to "run as Administrator" I just get a messagebox saying "The specified path does not exist", even though the file is definitely there, because I've found the file in file explorer and right-clicked it and selected run as administrator.

I had a windows 10 installation disk (even though I'm using Windows 7) and ran it so at least I could get access to a command prompt.  I tried running diskpart and changing the drive ID with UNIQUEID DISK ID=  but that prevented the disk being recognised by the system altogether so I changed it back again.  I also tried to enable the built in Administrator account using net user administrator /active:yes but even after I do this the Administrator doesn't show on the windows login screen so I think I may be setting it on the disk of the Windows 10 installation rather than my Windows 7 installation because no changes seem to persist.

I think it must be some security lockdown when it detected 2 identical drives on the same system or something like that.  I've spend a good day trying to fix it and I'm now stumped, hopefully someone can help!

UPDATE:

I've managed to enable the built in administrator account by booting the windows setup disk and then opening a command prompt.  From there I renamed magnify.exe to magnify1.exe and then copied cmd.exe and named it magnify.exe.  I then rebooted and at the windows 7 login screen I selected the magnifier on the Ease of access menu which launched an Admin cmd prompt.  From there I could enable the built in Administrator account and then use that to log in which solved some of my problems but when logging in using my original account the issue still persists.  I can now however "run as Administrator" from the built in administrator account without an error but I cannot access some things in control panel such as 'Add or remove user accounts", it just does nothing when I click it.  I can access local group policy editor however and it seems like I should be able to solve some issues with this although I'm not sure where to go from there

Answer (score 2):

The message that says “specified path issue “ is not a credential or permission issue (not on a good system).

I would say the clone went wrong.

(A) Re do the clone if you can.

(B) You may have to re install Windows 7, if you cannot otherwise repair it.

(C) Windows 7 is far out of support, so this is a good opportunity to upgrade to at least Windows 10.

Windows 7 lacks the Repair Install capabilities that later operating systems offer.

Comment: It's definitely a permissions issue (see UPDATE above).  Re-installing windows is always a last resort and I'm sure the issue can be fixed with a bit of perseverance.  I prefer Windows 7 to 10, I have a windows 10 laptop and it generally I find it easier to sort out problems with the Windows 7 machine because you have more control over it and there seems to be more data harvesting going on in Windows 10+ which I don't like

Comment: I have not seen Admin permissions give a path error unless (as I noted) the clone went quite wrong.

Comment: I saw your update and it confirms the clone error because Control Panel items are missing. Windows 7 does not have a decent Repair Install like later operating systems.

Comment: Now that I've managed to enable the built in admin account I don't get any path errors when I access the same files from that account.  I think the path error was misleading, it seems that from my usual account there was some permissions issue meaning that my account couldn't access the system files but was reported as them not being there when they definitely were, almost as though my account couldn't see them

Comment: Also the problem manifested itself on both drives, rather than just the new clone.  The original drive that I cloned from also has the same problem after cloning so that's why I think it can't have been an error while cloning or the original drive would be fine and it would just be the clone that had the issue but this is not the case

Comment: Obviously if the source drive now has the same issue as the clone, re-cloning will not help.  There was no issue with the source drive previously.  It seems you've voted my question down for some reason but I thought I gave plenty of details and explained what I have tried so I don't understand why you would do that just because I disagreed with your answer?  I appreciate you've tried to answer the question but the advice doesn't appear to be hugely helpful, formatting the drive and reinstalling a newer version of windows isn't really a solution as I have some old hardware & only win7 drvers

Comment: I know you gave lots of information, but there is not a lot you can do besides what I offered because Windows 7 is so old. There is not much way to repair it at this point.

Comment: I think I've actually managed to sort it out..  I'll update the question to say what I did

Comment: From your update, you may be able to use it but hardly to full potential because of the state of the operating system.

Comment: It seems the operating system is fine, it was some permissions issue.  All seems solved now anyway but I'll post an update if I notice any further issues - thanks

Comment: I think it just initially came up as a path error because the permissions wouldn't let the OS even 'see' that the file was there so it just reported that it didn't exist

Answer (score 0):

So after enabling the built in administrator account using the process stated in the question I still could not access user accounts within the control panel.  I then rebooted in Safe Mode, logged in as Administrator and was able to access the control panel.  From there I changed my original account to a standard user account and then back again to an administrator account.  I then logged out and logged back in to by own account and now it seems that I can access control panel items that I couldn't before and I can also "Run as administrator" without getting the path error.  So far at least, it seems the problem has been solved!

Comment: I've been using it all this week without issue so that seems to have sorted it

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem on both my Windows 10 machines, and stumbled on a solution after hours of searching. The trick is to rename the SSD using Explorer, but NOT by right-click on the left panel. Click on drive C in the right panel of the 'This PC' page and use the toolbar 'Rename' button. You get asked for "continue with admin privileges", and provided you actually chose a new name - problem solved after reboot. Goodness knows what logic is in play here, but it has to be a bug.